# Sql query to find the percentage difference of views between two given dates

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I am trying to write a sql query but i find some difficulties.What i want is:

Lets suppose we have a table where we store the times that a video have been watched, per day.
So for example:

- day: 14/11/2011, video_id: 3539, timeswatched: 125
- and: 15/11/2011, video_id: 3539, timeswatched: 162

(so the table stores video_id,day,timeswatched)

What i want is to make a billboard/chart type which show the percentage change of the timeswatched of the 8 top viewed (for today) videos between the dates: today and yesterday.
(note that a video may have not been watched at all today or yesterday - should this be a problem or not?)

So the result should be something like this: video-id: 3539 has +23% or -44% (or..) more/less views today (we need to know how to find the 23%)

Thanks!

Comment: It would be far more pratical do you your logic in PHP after you have your data set.

Comment: thanks, i think i agree with this, but what the sql query should be then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Top8.idvideo, (vtoday.times - vyesterday.times) / vtoday.times
From 
  (select 
     Idvideo from Nviews 
     Where day = Curdate()
   order by watches desc limit 8) top8 
  Inner join
   NViews vtoday 
       on vtoday.day = curdate()
       and vtoday.idvideo=top8.idvideo
  Left outer join
    NViews vyesterday
       On vyesterday.day= Date_add( curdate(), interval -1 day) and
           Vyesterday.idvideo = top8.idvideo
```

Comment: i got the main idea, thanks! it says "1052 Column 'idvideo' in field list is ambiguous" but i guess it has to do with some modifications i made to the code. anyway i will find a way to fix it. Thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: i always check the answer i use as solution at such questions, just give me some time to do my "tests" based on all solutions and then check the one i have relied on :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    videoWatchCountToday.timeswatched AS timeswatchedtoday,
    videoWatchCountYesterday.timeswatched AS timeswatchedyesterday,
    CASE
        WHEN COALESCE(videoWatchCountYesterday.timeswatched, 0) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE ROUND(100 * (videoWatchCountToday - videoWatchCountYesterday) / videoWatchCountYesterday, 0)
    END AS change
FROM
    videoWatchCount AS videoWatchCountToday
    LEFT JOIN videoWatchCount AS videoWatchCountYesterday ON
        videoWatchCountToday.video_id = videoWatchCountYesterday.video_id AND
        videoWatchCountYesterday.day = '2011-11-14'
WHERE
    videoWatchCountToday.video_id = 3539 AND
    videoWatchCountToday.day = '2011-11-15'
```

Comment: thanks, but we need this to be for the top 8 viewed today videos, not for a specific only video

Comment: Then take that code and modify it in the appropriate way. The purpose of this site is for you to ask how to do things you don't know how to do. It is not for you to get other people to do your job for you.

Comment: if i knew i would ask you to modify it :P but never mind. thanks anyway! :)

Comment: The best way to do it would probably be to replace `videoWatchCountToday` with a suitable subquery (to find today's 8 most watched videos) in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like (pseudo code):

```
yesterday = sql('SELECT timeswatched  FROM videos WHERE DATE(date_field) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)')
today = sql('SELECT timeswatched  FROM videos WHERE DATE(date_field) = CURRENT_DATE()')

if (today == 0 || yesterday == 0)
  // Special handling... 0 -> 10 views is an infinite increase.
else
  return (100 * yesterday / today) - 100;
```

Comment: Thank you! It's much simpler than the other solutions, so i will check it too. thanks!